# Customize appearence of bibliography entries from "biblatex"

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` for producing the bibliography in my document, and I wish to customize the entries. More specifically, I want to reduce the font size used for the URL as they tend to overflow.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: See [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

URLs are formatted (in part) by the `url` package. Adding

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\def\UrlFont{\scriptsize\tt}}
```

to your preamble should reduce the font size relative to the rest of the bibliography. (The bibliography font size is determined by the `biblatex` command `\bibfont`, defined as `\newcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}`.)

Comment: But doesn't this affect _all_ usage of `\url`? For instance, I'm using `\url` in some other places in the document.

Comment: @gablin It would. The `\AtBeginBibliography` hook can limit the change to within the bibliography - any use of `\url` before or after `\printbibliography` would be unaffected.